# Can I create a burnable image from a custom vagrant box

Tags: bootable-media, vagrant, embedded

I'd like to create and develop on a UbuntuMate image using vagrant. My question is, can I then create a burnable/bootable image of that OS and bootup on my raspberry pi?

Can an image lauched and developed on with vagrant then be turned into a bootable image?

How would I take my vagrant box and create a bootable image? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Do you want a live bootable system, like Mint/Ubuntu/Debian and countless others usually use as their main ISO to download & try & install? There are rather involved guides on how to make one of those, I think under "live iso". I'm unfamiliar with vagrant though

Comment: @Xen2050 I really want to be able to develop and customize and image in a virtual machine on my desktop, then burn that to a sd card and have it bootable on the raspberry pi